# SOLR - String field sorting

Tags: solr

I've a string field defined in SOLR that is populated with values such as "020001" and "50002" etc...
I require it to be a string field since I tokenize it for filtering purposes. Now, when I try to sort on this field it shows wrong order (not even ASCII). Is there a way to sort this field in the asc./desc. order? Thanks.

Comment: Please share what you tried and how it failed? Examples would be better. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you sort on a tokenized field, you're probably sorting on a multivalued field, which is something which will probably not give you the result you're expecting.

You can solve this by adding a dedicated field for sorting that contain the value you want to sort by, which will also allow you to use a more proper field type (such as tint) if you want to parse the value into an integer or still use it as a String value.